# java.sql.Date not inserted into datatables

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class wich contains:

```
@Column(name = "end_date")
private Date endDate;
```

and it's setter

```
public void setEndDate() {
    endDate = new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
    System.out.println(endDate);
}
```

When I'm calling the setter, and check again if the value is correct, everything's fine.(even `getEndDate().getClass()` ).
However, when I'm saving my object into PostgreSQL (`myObject.persist()`), there's no value on END_TIME column. Other values are correct.

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Also, I have to mention that hibernate is set to create SQL tables

Setter and getter:

```
public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
    setEndDate();
}
public Date getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}
```

Comment: Am I getting correctly that the column is called END_TIME on the table and end_date in the @Column tag? This might explain … :-)

Comment: With a private field, hibernate will use java bean standard setters and getters.  Can you post the other setters (that take an argument) and getters you have for that field on that bean?

Comment: OleV.V , it was me that wrote end_time uppercased. @AndyN, I don't have a setter wich takes a parameter, I guess there is the problem

Comment: I edited te post, and added setter/getter. It's still not working

Comment: @Adyzds It is not the case that @Olev.V was commenting on. The annotation is `end_date`. If the column is `end_time`, the annotation does not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. import java.util.Date instead of import java.sql.date
2. assign current date as per following code
3. default date assign while creating object of this entity if user need to change then using setter on run time
4. try this it will work

   ```
   @Column(name = "END_TIME")
   private Date endDate = new Date();

   public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
     this.endDate = endDate;
   }

   public Date getEndDate() {
       return endDate;
   }
   ```

Comment: It's working, thank's man!
Still don't understand why my approach wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

I use java.util.Date for this case, and change the mapping of your @Column as

```
@Column(name = "end_time")
private Date endDate = new Date();

public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
  this.endDate = endDate;
}

public Date getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}
```

Comment: the same thing. no value in database

Comment: I see you mark the column with end_date but checking the value in END_TIME, is that anything wrong?\

Comment: I told you above that I uppercased the column name. In database it's "end_time"

Comment: I edit answer and change the @column to end_time, logically, this column name is not case-sensitive